# Self modified Exceptions in c# , without the overhead

Tags: c#, exception, inheritance

In order to use the Exceptions mechanism  at the utmost, I'd like to create my own `Exceptions` objects.

I've read the relevant [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173163.aspx), and noticed the requirement to implement *at least* 4 constructors (Even if only to call base's constructor).

Assuming I going to have quit a few of these , it seems like waste of lines to write so many pointless code. as an alternative , I thought to do something like that:

```
Exception e = new Exception();
e.data.add(MY_SELF_DEFINED_EXCEPTION_CODE, MY_SELF_DEFINED_EXCEPTION_CODE);
throw e;
```

thus, losing the benefits of catching explicitly a self defined `Exception` .

Is there any lighter way  of creating self defined `Exceptions`, or another alternative to achieve that need?

Comment: If you really want to go this route, at least avoid inheriting `Exception` directly, and instead inherit from a specific exception already in the framework that most closely matches what you want to communicate. This way, someone catches those exception types will also be able to catch your exceptions.

Comment: Can you please specify what's wrong with that route? @JoelCoehoorn

Comment: Lines of code are pretty much irrelevant in that respect. Use the capabilities of your IDE to define a code template for exceptions that already has those four contructors and just replaces the correct exception class name, and then adding new exception types will not mean any more effort than creating any other POCO class.

Comment: It is *encouraged* to provide 4 constructors, "should" does not mean "must".  Since your alternative doesn't do anything like setting the Message or the InnerException, you don't have any use for those extra constructors either.  Maybe you'll find a use for them later, that can grow organically.  Making the constructors *internal* otherwise removes the "should" clause entirely.

Comment: @HansPassant ok, thanks. I don't sure I understand your last two sentences.